# В каких местах правильно писать "обоим", а в каких "обеим"?

Tags: грамматика

"Благодарен обоим" или "Благодарен обеим"?

Comment: В _таких местах_ будет правильно: если ДВЕ(обе, или ж.р.) женщины — обеих, если разного пола или мужчины(оба, разнополые или м.р.) — обоих.

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: В таких местах будет правильно: если ДВЕ(обе, или ж.р.) женщины — **обеих**, если разного пола или мужчины(оба, разнополые или м.р.) — **обоих**_. === ???  Гм... _Благодарен **обеих/обоих?**_ (См. вопрос Руслана.)